# Can't deploy even blank app to Windows IoT on RPi2

Tags: visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I'm using Windows 10 (10.0.14393) with enabled developer mode. 
I have latest update of Visual Studio 2015.

What I'm doing (note this is blank project with Windows IoT Extension for the UWP ver. 10.0.14393.0):

1. Start remote debugger at RPi and setup VS at address (without Authentication mode)
2. Start debugging (remote device, ARM)
3. I get this error message:

> The project "Test" needs to be deployed before it can be started.
>
> Verify the project is selected to be deployed in the Solution
>   Configuration Manager, or deploy it explicitly by clicking one of the
>   Deploy commands in the Build menu.

If I try to verify project I can't find it in there - I see only debug, release, new or edit.

4. I deploy (Build -> Deploy Solution) and I get this error message:

> Error DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. Failed to register
>   through new deployment pipeline. (0x80004005)
>
> Error DEP8000: Unexpected deployment failure : RemoteCommandException : Windows cannot register package
>   c820041a-da82-4e55-b136-83591b83e844 because it is in development mode
>   and the package is already installed. Increment the version number of
>   the package to be registered, or remove the old package for every user
>   on the system before registering this package. 0x80073cfb

I've tried to also deploy IoTCoreDefaultApp from [github](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples) and I get same errors.

---

About Raspberry: version 2 model B, fresh instalation of latest Windows IoT Core with latest update.

It looks like I'll go back to 10586, I want this version because it supports remote client.

---

What I've tried and failed to fix this:

1. Disable developer mode, deploy, enable developer mode
2. Delete package family folder at C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Packages\
3. Reboots RPi and PC

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the Solution in VS and restarting it? I've had issues deploying if the Pi has been restarted while VS has remained open. Can you access the Pi via PowerShell?... Just thinking about a network connectivity issue or blocked port.

Comment: As for step 3, what do you see as the debugger location? Right next to debug/release and the platform, right below the menu bar? I can't test it right now, but if I remember correctly, you need a combination of UWP and selecting a remote location for the debugger. Then simply hitting "run" should publish and attach the debugger. This explains it better than I do: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/appdeployment

Comment: @PaulAndrew I've tried what you said and it didn't help. Also I tried to disable Windows FIrewall with Defender and no change whatsoever. 
I can get into Pi via PowerShell.

Comment: @Poorkenny I'm sorry but I don't know what do you mean. I hope this can be useful [printscreen](http://i.imgur.com/0qLu7fh.png).
Well I remember when I had VS 2015 Update 2 and I used IoT Core ver 10586 it worked as you describe. For some reason I've it broken.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure what casued this problem. Since I need to move on in my project I went back to Windows IoT Core version 10586 and disabled auto-update by [this guide](http://developers.de/blogs/indraneel/archive/2016/04/22/how-to-disable-the-auto-update-on-windows-10-iot-core.aspx). Now it works fine. After October I'll try to get back to it and try to find what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select "Universal (Unencrypted Protocol)" for the Authentication Mode.  You can find this setting under the project Properties, Debug tab.[image: Authentication Mode]

Comment: I was trying use it too. Didn't work at all - same problem.
But if you want to use remote debugger you need to use no Authentication Mode and use default port 8116.